# Nested Classes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, oop, nested-class

I have 2 classes:

```
classdef Car
    properties 
        make;
    end
    methods
        function obj=Car(MyMake)
            obj.make=MyMake;
        end
    end
end
```

and

```
classdef Engine
    properties
        power;
    end
    methods
        function obj=Engine(bhp)
            obj.power=bhp;
        end
    end
end
```

How should I nest the Engine class within the Car class?

My idea is to do something along the lines of `Honda.Engine.Valve.getDiameter()`

In Python, all I would need to do is indent, I am not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can nest classes in Matlab. However, you can still achieve (more or less) your desired outcome using regular classes and assigning the "nested class" as a property of the "containing class."

For example:

```
classdef Nested
    methods
        function this=Nested()
            % Yep.
        end
    end
end

classdef Box
    properties
        nested
    end
    methods
        function this=Box()
            this.nested = Nested();
        end
    end
end
```

This won't allow the "nested" class to access the properties of the "containing" class, but it can provide the same nested access as you described.

For more information, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/saving-class-files.html. For example, this page states:

> Create a single, self-contained class definition file in a folder on
>   the MATLAB® path. The name of the file must match the class (and
>   constructor) name and must have the .m extension. Define the class
>   entirely in this file.

So, nested classes would violate this syntax because they are not contained in their own file on the Matlab path.

I haven't worked with Matlab packages before, but you may be able to work out your particular organization and functionality using packages. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

Good luck!

Comment: I felt I'd need to do the same. Thanks for the references.

Comment: +1 As far as scoping, unfortunately classes cannot be made private in MATLAB (so nested or inner classes are out of the question), they are always available on the global scope. As for namespacing, packages are indeed a solution, and you could create a directory structure as: `+pkg1/+pkg2/@ClassA` instantiated as `obj = pkg1.pkg2.ClassA`